# Receiving an 'int' object is not subscriptable error while trying to run a function inside another

Tags: python, project

Im trying to run a "battle simulation" program and then runs a series of subfunctions on each user turn.
Each subfunction works fine but when i try to run the whole thin i get an 'int' object is not subscriptable error. Here are the functiong affected:

```
def obter_posicao(u1):
    return u1[0]
def ordenar_unidades(tupuni):
    lista_p = []
    uni_ordenadas = []
    for u1 in tupuni:
        lista_p.append([obter_posicao(u1), u1])
    uni_em_order_per_p = sorted(lista_p, key=lambda x: (
        obter_pos_y(x[0]), obter_pos_x(x[0])))
    for p in range(len(lista_p)):
        uni_ordenadas.append(uni_em_order_per_p[p][1])
    return uni_ordenadas
def mover_unidade(m1, u1, p):
unit = list(u1)
    unit[0] = p
    u2 = tuple(unit)
    c = 0
    b = -1
    for u in m1[2]:
        if u1 == u:
            e1 = m1[2][:b] + u2 + m1[2][c:]
            e2 = ordenar_unidades(e1)
            m2 = (m1[0], m1[1], e2, m1[3])
            return m2
        b += 1
        c += 1
    for u in m1[3]:
        if u1 == u:
            e1 = m1[3][:b] + u2 + m1[3][c:]
            e2 = ordenar_unidades(e1)
            m2 = (m1[0], m1[1], m1[2], e2)
            return m2
        b += 1
        c += 1
```

and i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 10, in mover_unidade
  File "<input>", line 94, in ordenar_unidades
  File "<input>", line 45, in obter_posicao
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are much more likely to get help from the community if you do a few things before asking a question: 1. attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and show what you have done. 2. Avoid simply dumping your code and saying "I get this error". Instead, create a minimal and reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not only does this make it much easier for someone to figure out what your problem is, but often when you do this you discover the problem yourself before even posting the question

Comment: Its almost impossible to know what is happening because we can't see the data you are processing. Still its obvious from the error that where you are expecting a `list` in `u1` you are passing in an int.

Comment: As quamrana metnioned, your error is being pointed by traceback to obter_posicao where you simply return u1[0] but the issue is that u1 is not a list but an integer. So depending on your whole program, just return u1 or use a try except case to handle both situations

Comment: u1 is always a tuple of lenght 4 where u1[0] is the position that should be obtained, if i do obter_posicao(u1) it works well if i do ordenar_unidades(e1) where e1 is a tuple of units like u1 it also works. But as soon as i try to run mover_unidade i get that error that points back to other 5 functions